# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 Installation Prob

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I was running VS2010 Beta 1 and was wrapped this morning to see Beta 2 available. The (big) problem after the 'successful' installation though: On opening Visual Studio I get this message:

"The 'Visual Studio XML Editor Package' package did not load correctly."

If I continue through to a project, code windows will open okay but XAML windows won't.

Of course I uninstalled Beta 1 first, initially had the prob with Ultimate, then uninstalled and tried both Premium and Professional. The same issue with each.

Does anyone know what the issue might be and how to get it sorted? I pretty worn out after spending literally half the day trying to sort this out.

Thanks in advance for any help!

BTW I'm running Window 7 RC if that's any help.

Comment: I couldn't even install Beta2. I uninstalled Beta1, but Beta2 still complains it is installed...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on WindowsXP. In my case there were wrong registry entries that XmlEditor used (they refered to non-existing path of Beta 1 previously installed). Try following:

1. Start registry editor
2. Search old path in registry
3. For each entry that includes
   Microsoft.XmlEditor.dll in CodeBase
   parameter replace old path to
   correct

Answer (score 0):

While not entirely the anwswer, I loaded VS2010 Ultimate Beta 2 on my laptop (also running Windows 7 RC, but without VS2010 Beta 1) and all is well. It appears that there's some residue left over from the Beta 1 install. So at least the cause seems to have been identified.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your environment settings back to the default (tools -> options). Some settings in the text editors don't migrate well from earlier versions. Mine wouldn't open the C# editor which was kinda useless.